# Looping through variables and testing for user input

Tags: python

I want to write a program which asks the user questions and then checks for his answers. Here it is displayed with 3 questions and 3 answers. I was able to write it for a single question-answer pair, but am having difficulties using the same piece of code for all the pairs - I don't want to use explicit code for each question-answer pair as it would generate lot's of code.I would appreciate help with making it work for all questions.

```
Q1 = "Question 1 Is 30 fps more cinematic than 60 fps? - a)Yes, b)No, c)It's a matter of opinion or d)Nobody knows"
A1 = "b"
Q2 = "Question 2 Test Question? - a), b), c) or d)"
A2 = "b"
Q3 = "Question 3 If 10 + 9 is 19 what is 9 + 10? - a)19, b)20, c)21 or d)22"
A3 = "c"    
def quiz():
    n = 0
    while n < 3:
        n = n + 1

    if str(input(Q1)) == A1:
        print("Correct answer")
    else:
        print("Wrong Answer, Correct Answer is", A1) 

print(quiz())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lists to hold you questions and answers, and `zip` to iterate both.

```
qus = [Q1, Q2, Q3, ...]
ans = [A1, A2, A3, ...]

def  quiz():
    for q, a in zip(qus, ans):
        if str(input(q)) == a:
             print ("Correct answer")
        else:
             print("Wrong Answer, Correct Answer is", a)
quiz()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a data structure similar to that. This will also handle different question styles.

```
questions = [{"question": "Is 30 fps more cinematic than 60 fps?",
              "answers": {"a": "Yes",
                          "b": "No",
                          "c": "It's a matter of opinion",
                          "d": "Nobody knows"},
              "correct": "b"},
             {"question": "Question 2 Test Question?",
              "answers": {"a": "",
                          "b": "",
                          "c": "",
                          "d": ""},
              "correct": "b"},
             {"question": "Question 3 If 10 + 9 is 19 what is 9 + 10?",
              "answers": {"a": "19",
                          "b": "20",
                          "c": "21",
                          "d": "22"},
              "correct": "c"},
            ] 
def quiz():
    for question in questions:
        print(question["question"])
        for choice, answer in question["answers"].iteritems():
            print("{:s}: {:s}".format(choice, answer))

        if str(input()) == question["correct"]:
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer, Correct Answer is", question["correct"]) 
quiz()
```